# Is it safe to enable/disable bulk execution in CosmosClient during operation?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

In `CosmosClient` (Cosmos DB .NET SDK v3) there is a flag `AllowBulkExecution` in the `CosmosClientOptions` property for enabling/disabling bulk execution. Is it safe to change this flag in the middle of potentially lots of parallely ongoing operations (of course assuming that I modify the options in a thread-safe manner)? Or is it necessary to replace the `CosmosClient` instance by another instance with a different setting?

Background: I would like to optimize performance by enabling/disabling bulk execution depending on the rate of incoming modify requests to the `CosmosClient`.

Comment: What do you mean by optimize performance?

Comment: Maximizing throughput (= enable bulk) if the incoming request rate is high, minimizing latency (=disable bulk) if the request rate is low, based on some heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

Once the client is built, changing this flag has no effect. If you hold onto the `CosmosClientOptions` instance, switching the flag afterwards won't affect a client already built.

Part of the client creation clones the instance you passed as parameter: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/40ceaffa848ebb6e3f4efa255df49f38290ef539/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/ClientContextCore.cs#L61

Currently (although not sure if this will be called expected behavior), you can modify the flag through the `cosmosClient.CosmosClientOptions` property on an existing client instance.

If you would like the ability to disable or enable Bulk at the per-operation level, please share your feedback here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1496

EDIT: Adding clarification based on comments.

Comment: But I don't mean holding onto the instance, but accessing the `CosmosClientOptions` property from the `CosmosClient` instance. Setting `AllowBulkExecution` on that property should have immediate effect.

Comment: In this case, you can maintain two `CosmosClient` instances (one with batch on and  other normal) and switch between the two based on load. You anyway need to write a little separate code path for bulk (`Task.WhenAll`). Read more https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I don't think you necessarily need to call `Task.WhenAll` to benefit from bulk execution. Surely CosmosClient can't distinguish whether the tasks were awaited within a `Task.WhenAll` or whether they were awaited separately? If I understand correctly, CosmosClient will group all requests together that appear within a certain time window and send them off, either because the batch is full or the time window has elapsed. Can someone confirm?

Comment: That is correct, Task.WhenAll is not technically needed. You can have thousands of concurrent Tasks happening on different parts of your application and do what you described. Task.WhenAll is needed though in the case where the process you are doing happens to have all the information neatly together

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` is just one way of concurrency. You can definitely signal it in whatever way you want. I want you to note "...the SDK will construct batches and group operations, when the batch is full, it will get dispatched, but if the batch doesn’t fill up, there is a timer that will dispatch it to make sure they complete. This timer currently is 1 second. So if the batch does not get filled up (for example, you are just sending 50 concurrent operations), then the overall performance will be affected since the dispatch time is long (this is a particular point we want user feedback on)."

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I checked it in the source code: setting `AllowBulkExecution` in the `CosmosClientOptions` property of the `CosmosClient` instance has immediate effect.

Comment: Neat, that makes sense, since the CosmosClientOptions property of the CosmosClient is not the original one you passed as parameter, but a clone (I thought initially you wanted to change the instance you passed initially as input on the constructor).

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Just realized you're the author of that blog article. Can you answer the original question? I.e., is it allowed to switch the flag during operation?